# Error "Cannot read property of undefined" when wrapped in a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on a piece of code that is meant to handle multiple, small video elements on a single webpage but I am having trouble making the multiple progress bars sync with their respective videos.

([Current jsFiddle prototype](http://jsfiddle.net/DocW/59jow4wt/))

This piece of code `$(this).find("progress").attr("value", $("video", this)[0].currentTime);` seems to work inside the main function, but when I wrap it in another function with a `setTimeout` so the progress bar actually animates I get this error:

> "Cannot read property 'currentTime' of undefined at ***function***"

I've tried a few variations to see if I could get it working myself but I haven't been able to fix it by throwing code at the wall like I usually do.

Would someone be able to tell me why it's doing this?

Comment: Somehow missed this after spending a full day browsing through previous questions. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the `setTimeout` your `this` is not the main `this`. So your code doesn't work. To work in the setTimeout, you need to get the `this` before the setTimeout and the use it.

Example

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function(){
 // here use that
},100);
```

Comment: What if the value of this changes and we want the new value inside the timeout?

Comment: @Jus10 how it will be changed?

Comment: Well let's say you set the value of that to this, then you start a timer and this changes, then the timer runs out and now you're working with an old value that isn't up-to-date.

Comment: @Jus10 can you give an example of how 'this' would change?  'this' refers to the particular instance of that object.

Comment: It's old, but I think about this one:

showTooltip(e) {
  e.currentTarget.classList.add('tooltip');
  setTimeout(()=>e.currentTarget.classList.remove('tooltip'), 1000);
}

Answer (score 0):

You must change progress max to video duration or total time. and make it value to currenttime . then lets go

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var video = $('#YourVideoIDorClass').get(0`);
    video.addEventListener("onplaying", function () {
       progress.val = video.currentTime
    }, false);

})
```

Comment: My current code actually does change the progress bar's `max` and `value` attributes now that I've integrated Suren's answer. Your approach definitely looks more elegant than mine though, so I'll probably save it for when I try and optimize a bit more. Thanks kindly